# Azure DevOps Pipeline Calling Powershell Script - Create a .json file to read/write to

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

I would like to have a step in my Azure devOps deployment pipeline that calls a powershell script. Within the ps script I want to create a temp .json file in a folder on the Azure VM hosting the deployment agent. Then I want to write some stuff to the .json file then later on read it all within the powershell script.

In the Powershell script I am looking for an Az devOps environment variable that points to a directory on the VM the agent is running on where I'll have permissions to read/write to a .json file.

I don't know what the best env. variable to use or how to refer to it in a powershell script ?

Comment: Have found a web-page that may prove fruitful...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Answer (score 0):

Pass in $(Agent.TempDirectory) to the powershell script. See black underline below.

In powershell script...

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    $pSynapseWorkspaceName,
    $pPrivateEndpointName,
    $pSubscriptionID,           # storage account
    $pRgName,                   # storage account
    $pStorageAccountName,
    $pTempDir
 )
```

[image]

Then create a path with file name...

$tmpDir = "$pTempDir\{0}" -f "tmp_datalake_managed_private_endpoint.json"

Then using power-shell commands read and write to the file.